# Where exactly are the KL losses used after the forward pass?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-probability

I've noticed that the KL part of the loss is added to the list [`self._losses` of the `Layer` class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L117) when [`self.add_loss` is called from the `call` method](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.9.0/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/dense_variational.py#L308) of the `DenseVariational` (i.e. during the forward pass).

But how is this list `self._losses` (or the method `losses` of the same `Layer` class) treated during training? Where is it called from during training? For example, are they summed or average before adding them to the final loss? I would like to SEE the ACTUAL CODE.

I would like to know how exactly these losses are combined with the loss that you specify in the `fit` method. Can you provide me with the code that combines them? Note that I am interested in the Keras that is shipped with TensorFlow (because that's the one I am using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the part where the total loss is computed is in `compile` method of `Model` class, specifically in [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training.py#L229):

```
    # Compute total loss.
    # Used to keep track of the total loss value (stateless).
    # eg., total_loss = loss_weight_1 * output_1_loss_fn(...) +
    #                   loss_weight_2 * output_2_loss_fn(...) +
    #                   layer losses.
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
```

The `_prepare_total_loss` method adds the regularization and layer losses to the total loss (i.e. so all the losses are summed together) and then averages them over the batch axis in [these lines](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training.py#L711-L715):

```
        # Add regularization penalties and other layer-specific losses.
        for loss_tensor in self.losses:
            total_loss += loss_tensor

    return K.mean(total_loss)
```

Actually, `self.losses` is not the attribute of the `Model` class; rather, it's the [attribute of the parent class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/network.py#L400), i.e. `Network`, which returns all the layer-specific losses as a list. Further, to resolve any confusion, `total_loss` at above code is a single tensor which is eqaul to the **summation** of all the losses in the model (i.e. loss function values, and layer-specific losses). Note that loss functions by definition **must** return a single loss value per each input sample (not the whole batch). Therefore, `K.mean(total_loss)` would average all these values over the batch axis to one final loss value which should be minimized by optimizer.

---

As for the `tf.keras` this is more or less the same as native `keras`; however, the structures and flow of things is a bit different which are explained below.

First, in `compile` method of `Model` class [a loss container is created](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e4c6f288d4983bbe541afc656ac74b924b4550df/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L356-L357) which holds and computes value of loss functions:

```
  self.compiled_loss = compile_utils.LossesContainer(
      loss, loss_weights, output_names=self.output_names)
```

Next, in `train_step` method of `Model` class this container [is called](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e4c6f288d4983bbe541afc656ac74b924b4550df/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L570-L571) to compute the loss value of a batch:

```
  loss = self.compiled_loss(
      y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
```

As you can see above `self.losses` is passed to this container. The `self.losses`, as in native Keras implementation, contains all the layer-specific loss values with the only difference that in `tf.keras` [it's implemented](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef4e3be946946200ab60952051e5c206fa2c516d/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1140) in `Layer` class (instead of `Network` class as in native Keras). Note that `Model` is a subclass of `Network` which itself is a subclass of `Layer`. Now, let's see how `regularization_losses` would be treated in the `__call__` method of `LossesContainer` ([these lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef4e3be946946200ab60952051e5c206fa2c516d/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py#L221-L244)):

```
  if (loss_obj.reduction == losses_utils.ReductionV2.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE or
      loss_obj.reduction == losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO):
    loss_value = losses_utils.scale_loss_for_distribution(loss_value)


  loss_values.append(loss_value)
  loss_metric_values.append(loss_metric_value)


if regularization_losses:
  regularization_losses = losses_utils.cast_losses_to_common_dtype(
      regularization_losses)
  reg_loss = math_ops.add_n(regularization_losses)
  loss_metric_values.append(reg_loss)
  loss_values.append(losses_utils.scale_loss_for_distribution(reg_loss))


if loss_values:
  loss_metric_values = losses_utils.cast_losses_to_common_dtype(
      loss_metric_values)
  total_loss_metric_value = math_ops.add_n(loss_metric_values)
  self._loss_metric.update_state(
      total_loss_metric_value, sample_weight=batch_dim)


  loss_values = losses_utils.cast_losses_to_common_dtype(loss_values)
  total_loss = math_ops.add_n(loss_values)
  return total_loss
```

As you can see, `regularization_losses` will be added to the `total_loss` which would hold the summation of layer-specific losses and sum of average of all the loss functions over the batch axis (therefore, it would be a single value).

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer. So, all losses are added and then averaged? Averaging seems weird to me. Why not summing? Anyway, can you please point to the TF's version of Keras (rather than the standalone one)?

Comment: @nbro The averaging is over the batch axis, not the losses. As I said, the losses are added together resulting in a single tensor (i.e. `total_loss` is not a list, it's a tensor where losses are accumulated). My bad for not clarifying this. I'll fix it.

Comment: Does `K.mean(total_loss)` compute, by default, over the first axis (which I assume to be the batch axis)? Are you sure about that? I thought that, by default, `K.mean(total_loss)` averaged all elements across all axes. If `K.mean` calls TF's `reduce_mean`, what I said should be correct according to this documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean (i.e. the average would be across all elements).

Comment: @nbro Note that loss function by definition **must** return **only a single value for each input sample** (not the whole batch). Therefore, the `total_loss` would be a 1D tensor and `K.mean` gives you the average of all of them. I am %99 sure because that's what it should be. But maybe that %1 uncertainty proves me wrong. It could be easily verified by setting a trace at that line in debugging mode.

Comment: @nbro You are right about the fact that `K.mean` averages over all the axes by default, but that's not relevant here according to my previous comment.

Comment: Well, `total_loss` is a 1D vector (or tensor) that contains all losses (both output losses or layers' losses), then the average of this vector across all axes will not just average across the batch dimension, but also average the losses themselves. I was thinking that this is weird, i.e. you should average across the batch, but you probably shouldn't average these averages, but you should just sum them? Also, I didn't yet look at the details of how `total_loss` is generated, but it sounds weird that it's a 1d vector.

Comment: @nbro Again: it's not a 1D tensor of different losses; rather it's 1D tensor of summation of losses per each input sample, which its average gives you the average of final loss of all the samples in the batch. That's what I more or less assume it to be by looking at the code, but it could be that I am wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that `total_loss` already contains averages of losses? I am pretty sure that layers such as `DenseVariational` (because I looked at the source code), add their layer's loss (i.e. KL divergence, in this case) to the list of `losses`. Then this list of `losses` is accessed from the method `losses` of the class `Network`, as you noticed. In this method `losses`, the losses of each layer are added, with the operator `+=`, to the local variable list `losses` of this method with the same name (in the class `Network`). Now, the property `losses` of the layer is a list (I believe).

Comment: Then `losses += layer.losses` (in the `Network` class) should APPEND all elements of `layer.losses` to the list `losses`, so it is like extending that list (so it doesn't increase its dimensions). If that's the case, `total_loss` will contain all losses of all layers, so `K.mean` should average them.

Comment: @nbro Of course, `self.losses` is a list but it is iterated over and all of the tensors in it are added to the `total_loss` as shown in the code. In other words, `total_loss` is the **summation** of all the losses. Then its average is computed over all the samples which gives you a single final loss value for the batch. Note that a layer might return a single loss value for the whole batch (not per sample in the batch); but that's not a problem because that would be broadcasted again in summation and then in averaging it has the same contribution to the loss.

Comment: I don't think `total_loss` is the summation. It's a tensor that contains all losses (not summed yet), not the summation. Why do you say it's a summation? What part of code tells you they are summed? Where is this written?

Comment: @nbro A tensor is NOT a container, so it can't hold all the loss tensors. The summation is clear in the code above: `total_loss += tensor_loss`.

Comment: Ha, oops, how could I miss that part of the code that you highlighted?! Yeah, now I see that they are summed and that the average may be just across the batch dimension.

Comment: @nbro I am glad that you finally saw that line :) I was running out of ideas to explain this.

Comment: Maybe you could emphasize what we have been writing in this comment section in your answer, in case a moderator deletes these comments (so that this information is not  lost).

Comment: @nbro I tried to clarified that further. I also added the answer for `tf.keras`.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that. I will give you the bounty as soon as they allow me to do that ;)

Comment: @nbro Sure, I will take a look and let you know if I could find a solution.